# Как создать в цикле датасеты разного размера и как работать с ними?

Tags: python, pandas

Хочу создавать в цикле датасеты с разным количеством столбцов, чтобы можно было обращаться к ним, `train_data1`, `train_data2` и так далее.

```
for i in range(3):
    # features - здесь создается датасет Pandas с разным количеством признаков 
    train_data = features.iloc[i*100:i*100+500, :] # нужно сделать train_data+i
```

Как это реализовать?

Или каким образом из всех этих разных `train_data[123]` создать общую базу, чтобы было удобно обращаться к разным `train_data`?

Comment: два раза перечитал и не понял... Что значит `"нужно сделать train_data+i"`?

Comment: может вам просто словарь нужен с ключами: `["train1", "train2", "train3"]`?

Comment: @MaxU речь о массовом создании переменных с индексом. Но это скорее всего путь не красивы. Думаю словарь подойдет. Не понимаю, как реализовать через словарь синтаксически.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
train_data = {}

for i in range(1, 3+1):
    # features - здесь создается датасет Pandas с разным количеством признаков 
    train_data[f"train{i}"] = features.iloc[i*100:i*100+500, :]
```

PS [`f-string` (PEP-498) использованыый в ответе был добавлен в версии Python 3.6.](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) Для более старых версий используйте старый стиль форматирования:

```
train_data["train{}".format(i)] = features.iloc[i*100:i*100+500, :]
```

Comment: сделала через train_data["train"+str(i)] = features.iloc[i*100:i*100+500, :] с вашей помощью. Что то пропущено в синтаксисевашего ответа train_data[f"train{i}"] ?

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, а какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: 2.7 видимо описанная вами красота для 3? :)

Comment: @АннаЛебедева Красота описанна правильно, тк без метки [python-2.x] считается по-умолчанию, что это 3-я версия.